# cannot use isset() on the result of an expression

Tags: php

I have a block of code in some inherited work. It appears to be running ok, but  I suspect that's just because it hasn't needed to call this specific function yet.

```
function has($key)
{
    if (isset($this) && get_class($this)) {
        $obj = $key;
    }

    if (isset($this) && get_class($this)) {
        $obj = &JSW_Request::getInstance();
    }

    return isset(isset($this) && get_class($this)[$key]);
}
```

Running it through a syntax checker it reported the following error

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)

This is related to the code line

```
return isset(isset($this) && get_class($this)[$key]);
```

I can't relate what the suggested fix is to the code line to be honest, so I'm a bit lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is `$this` in your code??? Your function doesn't appear to be part of a class.  Did did you try `if(null !== $this)`??? Not enough code/context to tell.

Comment: In `isset(isset($this)` you are doing `isset($this)` which returns `true` or `false` and then you do an `isset()` on `true` or `false` which makes no sense.

Comment: you are only allowed to pass a variable to `isset` or `empty`. While `$this` is certainly a variable making the inner `isset` OK, you are passing `isset($this) && get_class($this)[$key]`to the outer `isset`, which is an expression, so thats the error

Comment: Just remove the outer `isset`, ie, `return isset($this) && get_class($this)[$key];`. That is legal code, however I agree with the other guy that `isset($this)` doesn't really make any sense

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `null` check instead of `isset` as follows:

```
if($var !== null){
 // your block of code
}
```